# Irregular array in compile

Tags: compile

I am trying to use Module wrapped in a Compile to produce two outputs. One is a vector, the other is a matrix. My actual example is rather complicated, but I managed to find a simple example problem that shows my problem.

I want the compiled function `hi` to give me a list with two entries. One is a vector the other is a matrix. I attempted the following

```
hi = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{a, b},
    a = ConstantArray[2.0, {n, n}];
    b = ConstantArray[3.0, {n}];
    {a, b}
    ]
   ];
```

When I evaluate for instance `hi[2]` I get a message saying

`CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 4; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`

I understand that `compile` cannot deal with irregular arrays, but I only need this at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not ideal because it requires global variables and because this won't allow you to use `Parallelize -> True`:

```
hi = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{a, b},
    a = Table[2.0, {n}, {n}];
    b = Table[3.0, {n}];
    
    (*further code*)
    
    $a = a;
    $b = b;
    ]
   ];
```

Then:

```
hi[3]
$a
$b
```

> {{2., 2., 2.}, {2., 2., 2.}, {2., 2., 2.}}
>
> {3., 3., 3.}

Make sure to copy the results to `$a$` and `$b` only in the end because every access to `$a$` and `$b` involves communication between the compiled function and the MathKernel and thus has some quite substantial overhead.

Also observe that `ConstantArray` is not compilable. But using table works as well.